# Braintree subscription expired for recurring payments -

Tags: mysql, cakephp, braintree

Let a customer has subscribed for a product for $2 monthly and his starting date is 11-May-2016 which ends on 10-June-2017, So my question was that, If a payment for a subscription fails, the subscription status will change to Past Due. How can I update subscriptions status for the corresponding customer in my database ?. How this process will be done ?

Comment: I think what you're is too broad, you're asking for an tutorial, and there is too little information to go on. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might give you a little insight in how to improve the question

Comment: While your question is too broad for stackoverflow, if you have something you would like to discuss with the CakePHP community - please join us on the #cakephp channel on irc.freenode.net, where we will be more than
happy to help answer your questions.
Also be sure to check out [The CakePHP Manual](http://book.cakephp.org) and
[The CakePHP online API](http://api.cakephp.org)